# Is there a name "phobia" for tape measures?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I'm really terrified of tape measures, such as the yellow metallic ones that some people use every day. When I was younger my dad always told me that I would get my fingers chopped off and my face sliced. I know now that is unlikely, but it still stuck with me and I have only been using strings to measure my walls. Is there a name "phobia" for tape measures?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in essence it is asking for a neologism. As well as that, It is too specific to be of any real use to any English learner.

Answer (score 7):

No.  There are lots of lists of "phobias", but most of these words are just joke words made by combining a Greek or Latin root to the suffix "-phobia".  These words are not used in psychiatric medicine, nor do they have any real currency in everyday English.

So making up phobia words is a word game.  You can play this game... Google translate tells me that the Greek for "tape measure" is "metrotainía" so you can get "Metrotainiaphobia".  But don't start believing that is a "real" word.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary has "Metrimaphobia"

Comment: Ancient Greek, or modern Greek?

Comment: modern, but since this is a game, who cares!  Although "tainia" is attested in ancient Greek, meaning "ribbon" or "tapeworm". And Metro- would be recognisable as ancient "metron"

Answer (score 5):

Since a name for this phobia doesn't exist as James K pointed out, you'd be best to say "I have a phobia of tape measures" and leave it at that.